# Listen to change in custom loader that is not made in an Activity/Fragment

Tags: android, android-loader

I have a ListFragment that works with a custom Loader (I do not want to use a ContentProvider).

I want to be able to change a record in the DB after clicking on a notification (for instance, to delete an item), and then if the ListFragment is alive, I want it to be notified.

Is there a way for me to do this using a Loader and without a ContentProvider?

Answer (score 0):

OK, since the Loader has to remain a part of the ListFragment life cycle, I guess a way to do this is with a local broadcast receiver. I will register and unregister on runtime and that way, if the Loader is alive, the ListFragment will be aware of that.